# Do 3rd party devices (e.g. Smart TV) have access iCloud Keychain?

Tags: icloud, password, keychain, appletv

I am trying to figure out how iCloud keychain works, especially for 3rd party devices and apps. Mainly using https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec0a319b35f/web and other partial information regarding syncing in different pages and sites.

For Apple devices, when I add a new device, it asks me for the password of an existing device. It makes sense to me as keychain is end-to-end encrypted.

I also saw there is a Windows iCloud Passwords application and, AFAIK, it only requires the 2nd factor to be an Apple device - I suspect that’s how the new device gets added to the sync circle.

I am wondering how that works when I add my Apple TV app in an LG Smart TV. I do so by using activation via QR code. Would the TV have access to the keychain? Or is it just some kind of a cookie that allows it to access Apple TV content? I would be very disturbed if the system would physically allow access to the keychain l, but just assuming the TV won’t request it - would be an attack. I hope it doesn’t just check device type. At the end of the day, I never have the TV the iCloud password.

Any idea on how I can be sure the TV has no access other than TV content? Any references that prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Software being software, you can't be 100% sure at the end. But I assume the question is mainly about the design of the Apple TV app running in the TV, and how it protects your data?

Comment: Can't really prove a negative...there's no evidence that it would, and reasonably it wouldn't. Apple doesn't publish documents listing every entity that doesn't have access to your iCloud Keychain.